# How much research effort is expected of Ask Ubuntu users?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, question-quality

What's the expected research effort show by an asker in their question?

---

I'm not asking about close votes! But normal up and downvotes based on the research level of a question. That's all.

Comment: I think that this is an open ended question.  It really depends on the user.

Comment: and on the question.

Comment: @Mitch I don't understand? What's the point of the discussion tag if it's not to discuss and what it matters the user?

Comment: @don.joey huh? Still not seeing what it matters? I'm expecting this discussion a metric on how much research is expected from AU users.

Answer (score 8):

### There's no lower threshold for research needed for questions.

And why would there be? Just look around. Many of our best, most viewed and best answered questions come from simple, clear and **completely unresearched** questions.

I've dallied around this in [previous iterations](http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/11926/revisions) of this answer but it's really that simple. There's *probably* a positive correlation between question quality and amount of research but I don't see that it's causative. Just as you can have great questions with no research, you can have a thoroughly researched question that's still pretty crap.

Explaining the problem is way more important than demanding some sort of proof of having already searched for an answer.

So forget "research" and focus on the core question quality.

Comment: And I've done rather a harsh edit on my answer to reflect that. You're right, I rambled on. All I needed to say was "no".

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's all I need to know. So, I will rather not answer questions if the first google hit would answer it.

Comment: Just because the question is easily googleable does not make it a bad question, some of our best questions are "easily googleable". I don't normally downvote questions because the answer is already on Google, although I do downvote duplicates, like all the mergelist questions we get.

Comment: Don't forget about the hover-over downvote message, though.